# Set width of bars in bar graph

Tags: android-graphview

Is there a way to control the width of the bars in a bar graph?  Currently I am seeing the first and last bars default to half the width of the remaining (middle) bars.

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705981/android-graphview-4-x-bar-graph-not-fitting/28809786#28809786

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, this is a [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705981/android-graphview-4-x-bar-graph-not-fitting/28809786#28809786): Anyway appears there have been quite a few changes between v3.1.3 and 4.0.0, as I also hit this one. The BarGraph specific logic in v3 of the library that shunted the viewport up and down half an xInterval, so you got a full width bar for the first and last entry on screen appears to have been dropped, but it's trivial to code around e.g.

```
double xInterval=1.0;
graphView.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
if (dataSeries instanceof BarGraphSeries ) {
    // Shunt the viewport, per v3.1.3 to show the full width of the first and last bars. 
    graphView.getViewport().setMinX(dataSeries.getLowestValueX() - (xInterval/2.0));
    graphView.getViewport().setMaxX(dataSeries.getHighestValueX() + (xInterval/2.0));
} else {
    graphView.getViewport().setMinX(dataSeries.getLowestValueX() );
    graphView.getViewport().setMaxX(dataSeries.getHighestValueX());
}
```